# For android firebase how to write the query for finding child by string matching of child of child's value?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: This is my firebase model]

Assume this script:

```
    private static DatabaseReference;
    mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");


    Query firebaseSearchQuery = mUserDatabase.child("service").orderByChild("serviceName").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText+"\uf8ff");


    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Workers, WorkerViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Workers, WorkerViewHolder>(
            Workers.class,
            R.layout.search_result_layout,
            WorkerViewHolder.class,
            firebaseSearchQuery
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(WorkerViewHolder viewHolder, Workers model, int position) {
             viewHolder.setDetails(model.getName(), model.getEmail());
        }
    };
```

What will be the query for finding users email by searching child of child's value (hardware) ?

Comment: the above code wont work anw, since there is a push id between the reference and child("service")

Comment: Thanks for replying #Peter Haddad , I wanted to know is there any way to match with value of child of push id ?

Comment: Firebase Database queries evaluate each child node under the location where you run the query. But the property it evaluates must be at a fixed path under each child. So you can't query double nested children like you have. As Alex answered this typically means that you should denormalize the data, i.e. create a top-level list of all services. Also see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested

Comment: Thanks boss #Frank van Puffelen . I denormalized the services data and it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to achieve this using this database structure.

First of all between `Users` node and `service` node there is another node, named `userId`, which does not appear in any reference. Between the `service` node and the child `serviceName` there is another node, `serviceId` node, which is the unique key generated by the `push()` method. I also don't see where are you looping to get those childrens. But these are not the actual problems.

In such cases as yours, you need to use a tehnique named in Firebase, denormalization and for that I recomend you see this tutorial, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA), for a better understanding.

So in your case, you need to create another node that will host only the services, so you can simply create a query. Unfortunately, Firebase does not allow you to query after multiple fields, so this is your only choice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm looking forward your idea :)